# PHP Caching Database Results and Input Variables

Tags: php, odbc

I have a fairly basic CRUD app (emphasis on the R) written in PHP. It connects to an OpenEdge database via [ODBC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php). Each page in the app basically returns the results of a database query and shows them in a table. Each page has a form at the top of it to allow users to specify parameters for the page's query. The form loads the same page, but passes the user parameters as GET variables.

I would like to be able to store the query results such that as long as the user does not specify new parameters that the page loads the same content (and does not fetch new data from the database) even on subsequent page loads (For example, the user could visit another page and come back to see the same data). Our reasoning is that we want the user to be able to analyze the data as they would a paper report (so that it does not change in the middle of analysis if the database were to be updated).

The way that I am currently doing this is using the SESSION variable. I have the page store both the input parameters and the results in the session. When the page is next loaded, it checks whether the SESSION and GET variables are set and then compares them to see if they are the same. If they are not the same, then the GET variables are used to query the database again. If they are the same, the cached data is used.

The problem with this approach is that it results in some very clunky code and does not scale very well with the number of input variables.

An example of the code for just one variable, `part` and the results for it, `part_orders`:

```
if (isset($_GET['part']) && isset($_SESSION['part'])){
    if(($_GET['part'] == $_SESSION['part']) && isset($_SESSION['part_orders'])){
        $part_orders = $_SESSION['part_orders'];
        $part = $_SESSION['part'];
    }
    else{
        $part = $_GET['part'];
        $part_orders = get_new_part_order_list($part, $query);

        $_SESSION['part_orders'] = $part_orders;
        $_SESSION['part'] = $part;
    }
}    
elseif(!isset($_GET['part']) && isset($_SESSION['part'])){
    if(isset($_SESSION['part_orders'])){
        $partial_part_no = $_SESSION['part'];
        $part_orders = $_SESSION['part_orders'];
        $part = '';
    }
    else{
        $part = $_SESSION['part'];
        $part_orders = get_new_part_order_list($part, $query);

        $_SESSION['part_orders'] = $part_orders;
        $_SESSION['part'] = $part;
    }
} 
elseif(isset($_GET['part']) && !isset($_SESSION['part'])){
    $part = $_GET['part'];
    $part_orders = get_new_part_order_list($part, $query);

    $_SESSION['part_orders'] = $part_orders;
    $_SESSION['part'] = $part;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Looking at some other questions here talked about writing the results to files, but that seems like a hassle to a a file for every page for every user.

Other suggestions seemed to only really work for queries that did not change (for example, loading a blog post).

Comment: What is the response time from this ODBC database? Do you really need any caching?

Comment: As I said in the OP, it is not a matter of response time, but rather a matter of data. We don't want to get updated data unless the user explicitly requests it.